# How does "var n=Number(3);" work?

Tags: javascript

I used `var n=Number(3);`by mistake (I should have used`var n=new Number(3);`), but I got n=3. As Number() is an object constructor, who can explain this?

Comment: Don't use number for anything except prototypes (`Number.prototype.bound=function(l,h){return h!==undefined?Math.max(Math.min(this,h),l):Math.min(this,l)}`). Use `var n = 3` instead.

Comment: @BoltClock Really? "I should have used `var n=new Number(3);`" (<em> on new)

Comment: Am I alone in thinking you should have used `var n = 3;`? (edit: I guess not.  :)

Comment: @blurd bjb agrees with the squirrel killer. :P

Comment: @bjb568 I can't set properties for n if i use "var n=3"

Comment: @user3257948 What do you mean by "properties"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An object constructor is also a function.

`Number`<sup>([*MDN doc*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number))</sup> as a function can be used to convert to a primitive type number.

```
> Number(3)
  3
> Number("3")
  3
> Number("A")
  NaN
> Number("2e2")
  200
> Number("0xff")
  255
> ["1", "2", "3"].map(Number)
  [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) explains:

> ## Description
>
> The primary uses for the Number object are:
>
> - If the argument cannot be converted into a number, it returns NaN.
> - In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the `new` operator), **`Number` can be used to perform a type conversion.**